# Web App breaks on windows phone after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, windows-phone-8

I am currently developing a web app that pulls metadata from a webservice.
It currently works in all browsers except that we get this weird issue on Windows Phone in Internet Explorer.
If you have a clear cache (first time load) it works with out a hitch, however once you refresh the page or navigate away and come back to the page the drop down lists fail to display data returned from the web service

**Before:**

[image: Before 1]
[image: Before 2]
[image: Before 3]

**After:**

[image: After 1]

We are using standard jQuery $.ajax calls to a local webservice 
It appears that in the after situation the success call back is being fired but the dropdowns aren't being rendered , and again this only happens after the page has successfully loaded once from a clean cache state and works fine in all other mobile browsers

the jquery code being used for the web service

```
function getAllPublications() {
    $('.error').addClass('dn');
    $('#selectYear').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#selectVehicle').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#selectManual').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.manual-section').hide();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/_Global/HttpHandlers/OwnersManuals/GetPublications.ashx",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.manuals-loader').hide();
            if (data.getPublicationYearModelDataResult.ErrorCode == 0) {
                allResults = data.getPublicationYearModelDataResult;
                extractUniqueYears(allResults);
                populateYearsDropdown();

            } else {
                $('.error.no-publication-error').removeClass('dn');
            }
            debugLog(JSON.stringify(data));

        },
        error: function (error) {
            $('.manuals-loader').hide();
            $('.error.api-error').removeClass('dn');
            console.log(error);

        }
    });
}

    function populateYearsDropdown() {
        $('#selectYear')
            .empty()
            .append($("<option />").val('-').html(__pleaseSelect))
            .removeAttr('disabled');

        $.each(years, function (val, text) {
            $('#selectYear').append($("<option />").val(text).html(text));
        });

    }
function extractUniqueYears(result) {
    years = [];
    if (result.PublicationYearModels != null) {
        $(result.PublicationYearModels).each(function (i, item) {
            if (item.YearModels != null) {
                $(item.YearModels).each(function (j, subItem) {
                    var year = subItem.year;
                    if (!checkIfYearExists(year))
                        years[years.length] = year;
                });
            }
        });
    }
    years.sort();
    years.reverse();
}
```

Note: I have tried adding no cache and cache expiration headers to the page and also tried using cache expiration meta tags on the page as well with no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up changing how the dropdown is initialized. 
The problem was the dropdown list init was firing too late because of the caching issue on windows and wiping out the dropdown list content after it had been populated 
we moved the logic into the DDL fill function and it fixed the issue so it clears all three DDLs when it is initially populated in the ajax function instead

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to trick browser into thinking that you're hitting the page for the first time using [`Location.reload(forcedReload)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload). Here's an example using cookies to prevent you from getting stuck in an infinite refresh loop:

```
var ie_mobile_reload = false, FORCED_RELOAD = true;

if /refresh=true/.test(document.cookie) {
  document.cookie = 'refresh=;'; /* Remove the refresh cookie */
  ie_mobile_reload = true;
  location.reload(FORCED_RELOAD);
}

/* IE Mobile only */
if /IEMobile/.test(navigator.userAgent) {
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (ie_mobile_reload) {
      document.cookie = 'refresh=true'; /* Set the refresh cookie */
    }
  };
}
```

I set `FORCED_RELOAD = true` to skip the cache and cause the page to be reloaded directly from the server.

Comment: we came up with another solutution but i don't think this would have worked in our sitation was it was never related to the reload of the page any load after the first load (not just refreshes) was breaking the DDLs